# How to configure Ubuntu for X11 client only?

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-10.04, xorg

I have Ubuntu 10.04 LTS server running within a VM (VMware Fusion) Currently I can only access the machine via character mode console. I would like to install whatever I need to install to run X11 client software on Ubuntu, without installing a full X11 Server. (I'll be using the X11 server within OS X, and ssh -X)

What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Check to see if it is working already:

   ```
   ssh -X serpents-hold emacs
   ```

That's all I needed to do. I had chosen to install sshd during the set up of the server. I'm not sure how the xauth package was installed.

Comment: *xauth* is pulled in by the base *xorg* package and is recommended by the *openssh-server* package.  i think Ubuntu's default Apt policy is to install recommended packages automatically; that's probably how it got installed on your system.

Answer (score 2):

Install sshd and xauth.

Oh yeah, start sshd as well. But I figure you already knew that bit.

Comment: I'm new to this, so best not to assume. I believe sshd is already installed and running, because I can ssh to Ubuntu from OS X already. To install xauth I typed `sudo apt-get install xauth`it says xauth is already installed.

Comment: Okay, then you assuming X forwarding hasn't been disabled in the server config, you should be good to go with `ssh -X`.

Comment: +1 for the helpfull advice. However, and this is because I didn't know what I was doing initially and gave poor information, this answer was not the solution.